# Where do I find System.Windows.Interactivity as redistributable?

Tags: .net, wpf

I tried downloading Blend 3 but even with that installed I can't find the file under .NET. 
If I try to add a reference from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend 3\Interactivity\Libraries\WPF and use this code http://pastebin.com/VdeRyPdv I get an error that the file was not found. It also adds a lot of folders like en, de es fr etc to my debug folder.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Expression Blend SDK for .NET 4 (WPF) is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801).

(Update 2023) - @Raif's answer appears to still be valid. https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

Comment: The link is now dead.

Comment: @MikeRosoft unsurprising that 12 years later things have disappeared - but it seems that Raif's answer is still available ... see https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/

Answer (score 3):

The mvvm light toolkit includes a standalone version of this assembly

Answer (score 2):

Maybe in the [Blend 3 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en)?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the WPF version from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/).